# Transform scanned PDF documents into Excel using OCR

Tags: data

I have a task that is to convert cable schedules into an Excel spreadsheet. I have tried a few different OCR (Optical Character Recognition) things such as websites, code in R (tesseract), javascript, data from picture in excel and looked into C.

So far none of these have worked. I believe the main 3 errors are that I have are that;

1. If there are multiple rows with the same information in a column there is just an arrow pointing down for however long it is. A lot of things I have found seem to thing that it randomly splits into 2 columns.
2. The layout of the documents might be an issue as it is in the format of an engineering drawing that has been exported from AutoCad with the reference grid all around it.
3. It is a non-editable pdf and was made by basically drawing it in AutoCad and thus doesn't technically have text hence why I am trying OCR

The layout of the excel that is exported doesn't matter as long as the data is right as I can just manually copy and paste the columns into the correct format.

I have approximately 350 of these to do and only December/January to do it. With searching for other methods along with trying manually I can complete about 4 every day assuming no distractions. As that shows those numbers do not line up with the timeline hence why I am asking if anyone here knows any options.

What have I tried;

1. Random online pdf to excel converters

- They either output a corrupted table or just add the table as in image in excel.

2. Adobe's built in pdf to excel.

- I don't have access to this and I haven't perused access to this as using Adobe's online version it has the same issues as 1.

3. Excel's data from picture function.

- doesn't read the data correctly. it converts everything wrong even basic words like "TRAY" it will fail to get a single letter correct.

4. Using Tesseract on RStudio

- This method was found on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979857/doing-ocr-with-r however it struggles with the layout of the cable schedule and only able to extract a few parts.
- This may still be viable as I am not very experienced with either R or tesseract.

5. OneNote's built in OCR

- basically makes hieroglyphs from the document

6. docsumo.com is something that somewhat works. this is what I have been using to extract the larger columns however it struggles with some of the smaller columns so about half of it still needs to be entered manually.

- https://www.docsumo.com/free-tools/extract-tables-from-pdf-images

Below is an example of what I am trying to extract.[image: example of cable schedule with information removed]

It is mainly the data inside the red box that I need to extract, all the cable schedules are in this format.

Comment: Interesting task. However, I would forget about getting the layout from some OCR here correctly. Instead, I would try to implement a semiautomatic process where one does only scan  text of one or more rows (inside some marked rectangle) in one column to the clipboard and then its content from there into some prepared Excel template. Still I don't know if this will become faster than 4 pages per day. If the deadline is fixed, you will probably need more persons.

Comment: You mention PDF to Excel converters - are you doing a direct conversion for ".pdf" to ".xlsx"? Or have you also considered ".pdf" to ".txt" or ".csv" as intermediate steps to an ".xlsx" import via VBA tooling? Mainly asking because my immediate thought was to use [pdftotext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310416/how-to-extract-table-data-from-pdf-as-csv-from-the-command-line) to get everything into a file, then reading that into an Excel sheet and picking the cells I wanted from a somewhat inconsistent cell placement, but I suspect you have tried that as well?

Comment: @DocBrown That is an interesting idea I'll have to look into it. The deadline is fixed and I do have a second person working on it. Thank you for your help

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st I have looked at that briefly however I never got too deep into it. It looks quite promising do you think that the format of the pdf especially with all the stuff around the outside will cause issues for this? if so do you think that just using something such as snippy tool to crop out everything else out then doing that would fix the formatting issues?

Comment: @Iestyn: I suspect, although I don't have Excel locally here to test with unfortunately, one of the big issues will be seeing what happens to the rotated text on the edges, but the arrows on the borders of the paper likely won't be an issue - at worst, you can always skip over those cells.

Other than that, the arrow approach likely turns into lines of "|" and "v" "^",, or something similar - parsing those could be annoying to duplicate values. The biggest issue may come up with rows misaligning - and having to search for the next value in a cell if it can't be empty normally.

Comment: For a semiautomatic process, I would also consider to write some VBA macro for easier drawing of the vertical arrows.

Comment: Those are exports from a CAD drawing. Do you still have the original DXF/DWG files? If the original is in Eplan, the data can be extracted straight from the source to Excel.

Comment: ... since you did not mention it: I would recommend trying Abbyy Fine Reader (they offer a free trial version),  one of the best OCR programs I used some years ago. Don't expect it to solve your issues automatically, but it may be a good option for a semiautomatic process.

Comment: I assume that cloud-based AI/recognition services such as Azure's Form Recogniser would be able to do some of the heavy lifting here.   I have not used such services myself, but I would expect Azure/AWS/GCP are likely to have the benefit of enormous training models so are likely to be fairly good with accuracy/confidence.

Answer (score 0):

We do not answer questions for finding or using programming tools on this site.

However, from a software engineering point of view, I think the main question is how much automation is it worth to achieve, and for which parts of the process, to either keep the total effort small or to hold the deadline.

On the one end of the spectrum, there is the idea to find or create the ultimate OCR tool, where one just feeds a PDF into a black box and gets a perfectly ready-made Excel document out of it. On the other end of the spectrum, one does not invest any time in automation and tries to solve the problem manually, maybe by assigning a lot of people to the task (maybe some low price workers found over some crowdworking portal).

Both approaches will probably be not ideal, the first one is technically unrealistic, the second one will probably cause too much management effort. Coordinating a bigger group of people for this task requires finding them, making a contract, teaching them thr requirements, applying quality assurance, and lots of more things which can in the end cost more time and money than it saves. Given your current timeline, [Brook's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27s_law) is likely to kill the project.

So your best option is probably to find a middle ground. My idea here would be to solve parts of the task automatically, and some parts of it manually. Some ideas:

- Start with some document template which is already formatted correctly, contains all repeating text like the headlines. If the template needs some variation, write some VBA macro which allows to apply this variation.
- Use existing OCR software which allows extracting text from a rectangular frame one draws interactively over a column in the PDF, then copy the text into the Excel template
- Implement some VBA macro for easier drawing / redrawing the vertical arrows

And now think further into this direction, after creating the first few tables: are there more tedious tasks which you can automate here? Maybe some consistency checking / quality assurance tasks? But always have this classical XKCD in mind:

[image: Is it worth the time?]

So when you invest one day into programming for some automation, it should save you at least 1,5 minutes per table (taking the 350 tables into account), otherwise the forget about the automation and do the task manually.

Comment: I suspect part of the problem is the deadline they have to complete these - their estimate based on current manual processing indicates they won't complete the task in full manually, hence the focus on automation. If the automation can shave off 2 months or more- that chart doesn't indicate how much time to spend on it. They are looking for a technique, which may involve different tooling, but doesn't necessarily require that. It could fit stackoverflow rather than engineering, but I think they're asking if there's an X-Y problem here in their attempted solution.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st: The above answer is providing an accurate approach on how to get to the end result the fastest/most efficiently (the two are equivalent if you assume that you will only work on this problem and nothing else). If the given deadline is tighter than the most efficient approach, the deadline is worth nothing.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st: It's also not about exactly what the chart contains but rather what it _conveys_. The numbers are off for OP's scenario anyway (given that this chart spreads the effort over 5 years instead of OP's 2 months) but the overall lesson is a relevant one.